# Writing an app with its own "web browser"

Tags: .net, winforms, html, web-applications, browser

This is the first "real" program that I've ever attempted writing myself. Everything up till now has mostly been along the lines of a homework assignment. So I'm not necessarily the most experienced, but I'm an eager learner :)

I want to write an app that sits on top of other websites. Its main use will be to categorize and store research. Basically think of it like a very advanced bookmarking app.

It would be great if I could make it compatible with many different operating systems. I love the idea of a web app, but I get the impression that some of the features that I want are well beyond what even HTML 5 and JavaScript can offer right now (if ever).

I want a few features from modern browsers to be built in, such as full tab support and an intelligent URL bar (searches automatically, for example). If I were building a Windows program, what's the best way to do this? Should I try to hack FireFox or Chromium into it? Or is using a WebBrowser form probably my best bet?

Also, is there any way I can do this whereby it will be feasible to port it to OSX and potentially iOS and Android down the road?